# How to estimate the Graphite(whisper) database size when I'm using it in monitoring Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, monitoring, graphite

I'm gonna set up monitoring Spark application via `$SPARK_HOME/conf/metrics.propetries`. 
And decided to use Graphite.

Is there any way to estimate the database size of Graphite especially for monitoring Spark application?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what you are monitoring, Graphite has its own configuration about retention and rollup of metrics. It stores file (called whisper) per metric and you can use the calculator to estimate how much disk space it can take https://m30m.github.io/whisper-calculator/